# bash until loop waiting for docker to be running - not working:

Tags: bash, docker

Can you see why this is not working?

```
function WaitForUp(){
    echo $1
    docker inspect -f {{.State.Status}} $1
    until [ "docker inspect -f {{.State.Status}} $1"=="running" ]; do
        sleep 0.1;
        echo "Loopo"
    done;
}
```

Comment: `until [ "$(docker inspect -f {{.State.Status}} $1)" == "running" ]; do`

Comment: Yes my friend - thanks. Do you want to answer?

Comment: Its quite a trivial one IMHO, we have plenty of similar questions around. You could delete it or self answer it explaining more about what you were trying to accomplish in the function

Answer (score 0):

As it is written, `"docker inspect -f {{.State.Status}} $1"` is a string. bash substitutes the `$1`, then compares the resulting string against `"running"`, which is always different.

As pointed out in the comment by Inian, you can use `"$(...)"` to let bash execute `...` as a command, and substitute the command output in the string.